# Delay content of test of Cloud Functions with Mocha

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, mocha.js

I am trying to test a Cloud Function that interact with a Firestore database. I am following the documentation for testing my function using firebase-functions-test in online mode and mocha (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing)

Since the function I want to test delete a document in a collection, I first created a fake document that I push to the db, inside my test.
Then I called with the wrap my function to test. It's asynchronous, so it takes a bit of time.

What I want to verify is that the document has been correctly removed. But the call to get the document and then the assert is sometimes faster than my actual function doing the delete. I would like to add a small delay before doing the verification.

I tried to add a settimeout, but the test returns 'passed' without waiting for the code inside the timeout to run and checking the assert.

Here is my test. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const myFunctions = require('../src/delete_notification.ts');

    it('delete notification of db more than 7 days old', async() => {

        // create test notification in db
        const notificationToDeleteId = 'TEST_1234567890';
        const notificationToDelete = {
            uid: notificationToDeleteId,
            createdOn: '2021-01-01T00:00:00.00000'
        };

        await admin.firestore().collection('notifications')
                 .doc(notificationToDeleteId)
                 .set(notificationToDelete);

        // call the cloud function
        const wrapped = test.wrap(myFunctions.deleteNotificationAfter7Days);
        await wrapped();

        //this code needs to be delayed by a few seconds

        return admin.firestore()
            .collection('notifications')
            .doc(notificationToDeleteId).get().then((deleteDoc) => {
                //console.log(deleteDoc.data());
                assert.equal(deleteDoc.data(), null);
        });
    });
```

Update :

I tried this code:

```
return wrapped().then(() => {
            return setTimeout(() => {
              return admin.firestore().collection('notifications').doc(notificationToDeleteId)
                  .get().then((deleteDoc) => {
                      console.log(deleteDoc.data());
                      assert.equal(deleteDoc.data(), null);
                  });
            }, 5000)
        });
```

while making sure my function called does NOT delete the document. Like that I expect my test to failed. But with this code below (with the settimeout) the test passes all the time. It's the same with setInterval.

[image]

And here is the function I am trying to test:

```
 import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
    import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
    
    if (admin.apps.length === 0) admin.initializeApp();
    const db = admin.firestore();
    
    // run every  7 days
    export const deleteNotificationAfter7Days = functions
    .region('europe-west6')
    .pubsub
    .schedule('every 24 hours')
    .timeZone('Africa/Accra')
    .onRun(async context => {
    
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const currentDateMinus7Days = new Date(currentDate.getTime() - 604800000);
        const currentDateMinus7DaysString = currentDateMinus7Days.toISOString();
    
        //console.log("date minus 7 days " + currentDateMinus7DaysString);
    
       try {
            const querySnapshot = await db.collection('notifications').where("createdOn", "<", currentDateMinus7DaysString).get();
            if(querySnapshot.empty) return;
    
            querySnapshot.forEach( async function(doc){
           

     const notificationId = doc.id;

            //console.log('notificationId id ' + notificationId);
            await deleteNotification(notificationId);
            return;
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error deleting notifications ' + error);
    }
    return;
});

async function deleteNotification(notificationId : string) {

    //console.log('DELETE FROM NOTIFICATION');

    return db.collection('notifications')
        .doc(notificationId)
        .delete()
        .then(function() {
            console.log('Notification deleted');
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            throw error;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The odd behaviour you see and wrongly are trying to work around is caused by your incorrectly implemented Cloud Function.

Currently your function does the following:

- Find all notifications older than 7 days and start a delete operation for each one.
- End the Cloud Function without waiting for the above to finish.

The second point is why you are having to wait a few seconds before deleting the data in the database.

In a deployed function, as soon as the function returns, **all further actions should be treated as if they will never be executed** [as documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#do_not_start_background_activities). An "inactive" function might be terminated at any time, is severely throttled and any network calls you make (like deleting documents) may never be executed.

---

In your code you use `const notificationId = doc.id; deleteNotificationId(notificationId)` to delete your notifications. This can be replaced by `doc.ref.delete()` to serve the same purpose.

To fix your function, we need to wait for the delete operations to finish before returning from the function and ending its lifecycle.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
    
if (admin.apps.length === 0) admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();
    
export const deleteNotificationAfter7Days = functions
  .region('europe-west6')
  .pubsub
  .schedule('every 24 hours')
  .timeZone('Africa/Accra')
  .onRun(async context => {
    
    const currentDateMinus7Days = new Date(Date.now() - 604800000);
    const currentDateMinus7DaysString = currentDateMinus7Days.toISOString();
    
    try {
      const querySnapshot = await db.collection('notifications').where("createdOn", "<", currentDateMinus7DaysString).get();
      if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        console.log("No notification documents to clean up. Aborted.");
        return;
      }
    
      const deleteDocPromises = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        deleteDocPromises.push(doc.ref.delete());
      });

      // wait for all operations to complete
      await Promise.all(deleteDocPromises);

      console.log("All old notifications cleaned up successfully.");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Unexpected error deleting old notifications: ' + error);
    }
});
```

With your current function (including the code above), if any single document's delete operation fails, the entire function crashes. While you could trap the errors so that this doesn't happen, if you had 200 documents to delete and all of them failed, you would have 200 errors and 200 failed network requests. Instead, you should set a threshold so that after you get X errors it crashes the function. This allows a few to fail while still deleting the others and the ones that failed would be reattempted the next time the function runs.

```
const deleteDocPromises = [];

let errorCount = 0;
const handleError = (error: any) => {
  if (++errorCount > 10) {
    throw new Error("Error threshold exceeded");
  return error;
};

querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
  deleteDocPromises.push(
    doc.ref
      .delete()
      .catch(handleError)
  );
});
```

---

Another improvement would be to use batches to perform the deletions reducing the networking overhead of your function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
    
if (admin.apps.length === 0) admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();
    
export const deleteNotificationAfter7Days = functions
  .region('europe-west6')
  .pubsub
  .schedule('every 24 hours')
  .timeZone('Africa/Accra')
  .onRun(async context => {
    
    const currentDateMinus7Days = new Date(Date.now() - 604800000);
    const currentDateMinus7DaysString = currentDateMinus7Days.toISOString();
    
    try {
      const querySnapshot = await db.collection('notifications').where("createdOn", "<", currentDateMinus7DaysString).get();
      if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        console.log("No notification documents to clean up. Aborted.");
        return;
      }
    
      let currentBatch = db.batch(), currentBatchCount = 0;
      const batches = [currentBatch];
   
      // for each document, queue its deletion
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        if (++currentBatchCount > 500) {
          // more than 500 operations in the current batch, start a new one
          currentBatch = db.batch();
          currentBatchCount = 1;
          batches.push(currentBatch);
        }

        currentBatch.delete(doc.ref);
      });

      // wait for all operations to complete
      const batchErrors = await Promise.all(batches.map(b => {
        return b.commit()
          .then(
            () => null,
            (error) => error // trap errors so other batches can still complete
          );
      }));

      const errorCodeSummary: Record<string, number> = {};
      let errorCount = 0;

      batchErrors
        .forEach((error) => {
          if (error === null)
            return;

          errorCount++;
          const errorCode = error.code || "unknown";
          errorCodeSummary[errorCode] = (errorCodeSummary[errorCode] || 0) + 1;
        });

      if (errorCount > 0) {
        console.error(
          `${errorCount}/${batches.length} batches failed while cleaning up old notifications. ` +
          `They had these error codes: ${JSON.stringify(errorCodeSummary)}`
        );
      } else {
        console.log("All old notifications cleaned up successfully.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Unexpected error deleting old notifications: ' + error);
    }
});
```

**Note:** You could make it even more efficient by using the [REST API's List](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/list) to get just the list of document IDs (no interior document data) by using a field mask of `["__name__"]` and appropriate query parameters.

---

With either of the above fixes, your test becomes:

```
// run the function
await wrapped();

// check function result
const deletedDocSnapshot = await admin.firestore()
  .collection('notifications')
  .doc(notificationToDeleteId)
  .get();

assert.equal(deletedDocSnapshot.data(), null);
```

---

However, to also answer the original question, this function will create an awaitable setTimeout:

```
function setTimeoutPromise(callback: (...args: any[]) => any | Promise<any>, timeoutMS: number, ...args: any[]) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout((...args) => {
      try {
        Promise.resolve(callback(...args))
          .then(resolve, reject); // <-- handles Promise-based errors
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err); // <-- handles errors if `callback()` isn't returning a Promise
      }
    }, timeoutMS, ...args);
  });
}
```

Then to use it:

```
// run the function
await wrapped();

await setTimeoutPromise(() => {
  return admin.firestore()
    .collection('notifications')
    .doc(notificationToDeleteId)
    .get()
    .then((deleteDoc) => {
      //console.log(deleteDoc.data());
      assert.equal(deleteDoc.data(), null);
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!! I really appreciate all your explanations and your improvements!! I understand now my many mistakes, and I'm going to change a lot in my cloud functions following your answer! Really again thank you for the time you took answering this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the `.wrap()` is. Does that return a promise?
If you want to use `.setTimeout()`, you can try it this way:

```
const wrapped = test.wrap(myFunctions.deleteNotificationAfter7Days);
await wrapped();

setTimeout(() => {
  return admin.firestore().collection('notifications').doc(notificationToDeleteId)
      .get().then((deleteDoc) => {
          //console.log(deleteDoc.data());
          assert.equal(deleteDoc.data(), null);
      });
}, 5000)
```

or you can use `setInterval()` which runs every X seconds and repeats itself if the tasks is still unfinished.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. I edited my question above after trying with your proposed code. It's not working, the test always passes even when I make changes to expect a failed...

Comment: @ama could you give more details on test.wrap() ?

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#test-background and the API ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/test/test#.wrap

Comment: I also added above the function I am trying to test. The issue might come from there.